# Cannot import "compass/utilities/sprites"; into my sass file

Tags: sass, compass-sass, compass

I've been trying to import the sprites module to my SASS stylesheet, but I got the following error:

```
/*
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/utilities/sprites.
       Load path: /Users/ToanNguyen/Documents/SourceCode/CSS/helloCompass/sass
        on line 1 of sass/Spriting.scss

1: @import "compass/utilities/sprites";

Backtrace:
sass/Spriting.scss:1
/Users/ToanNguyen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:66:in `rescue in import'
```

I have sass 3.4.10 and compass installed, and have a config file like this:[image: Sass Config]

And the content of the scss file is

```
**@import "compass/utilities/sprites";**
```

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Are you using the `compass` command?

Comment: Yes I use compass --watch sass:stylesheets

Comment: That isn't possible.  When I run that command, I get this error:  `Error: invalid option: --watch`.  The command should just be `compass watch`.  What version of Compass are you using?

Comment: You are right. I made mistake when posted the command compass watch sass:stylesheets